# Laravel accessing database record with id could not return a value

Tags: mongodb, php-7, laravel-5.5

```
     $userData = DB::table('user_data_collection')->where('user_id', 
      $user_id)->first();
     return $userData;
```

Above is the code I am using jessengers/mongodb in a Laravel 5.5 Application and fetching a record from a collection in my controller but it returns a null value.

As I am running following query it is returning a specific first record in a collection.

```
      $userData = DB::table('user_data_collection')->first();
     return $userData;
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$userData = DB::table('user_data_collection')->find($user_id);
     return $userData;